# Excel VBA: Append Text to Multiline Cells Depending on Line Color

Tags: excel, vba

I have an enormous set of data in an Excel sheet that has been compiled over a number of years with multiple entries per line.  I am using Power Query to split multiline cells into individual cells, but the data is also color-coded, with red lines representing a user who is no longer with the company.  As Power Query has no ability to preserve formatting, I need to append text to each line that is red, which I can then use to create a new column in Power Query to represent that status.

What's worse is that some cells are single-line, some are multiline, and there are 10 columns of identical data (D through M).

Example data below.

[Before]

[image]

[After]

[image]

I found another user's code example here, which seems to be on the right track for me, but I can't figure out how to isolate only lines that are red.

```
Public Sub RePrint()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set MyRange = Range("A1")
MyArray = Split(MyRange, Chr(10))
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    MyArray(i) = MyArray(i) & " Text" & i
Next i

MyRange = Join(MyArray, Chr(10))

End Sub
```

Any assistance in creating a one-time macro to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Solved using Paul's code below, with some additions for looping through a selection.

```
Sub Append()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim myChars As Long
Dim myColorindex As Variant

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each MyRange In selectedRange.Cells
myChars = 1
MyArray = Split(MyRange, Chr(10))
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    myColorindex = MyRange.Characters(myChars, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    myChars = myChars + Len(MyArray(i)) + 1
    If myColorindex = 3 Then
        MyArray(i) = MyArray(i) & "*term"
    Else
        MyArray(i) = MyArray(i)
    End If
Next i
MyRange = Join(MyArray, Chr(10))
Next MyRange

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't assign the text to an array of strings as that will not include the colour information (or any other formatting). You would need to loop through the content of the cell directly and add the desired text there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work but the array will not include color information. So, you have to keep track of where you are in the original text, and check for the color inside the cell.

Like this:

```
Sub RePrint()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim myChars As Long
Dim myColorindex As Variant

Set MyRange = Range("A1")
myChars = 1
MyArray = Split(MyRange, Chr(10))
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    myColorindex = MyRange.Characters(myChars, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    myChars = myChars + Len(MyArray(i)) + 1
    If myColorindex = 3 Then
        MyArray(i) = MyArray(i) & " *term"
    Else
        MyArray(i) = MyArray(i)
    End If
Next i
MyRange = Join(MyArray, Chr(10))

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to use this in a loop through a selection of cells, but black text is not preserved.  While the end color is irrelevant for my needs, I wonder if there's a way to preserve text that was originally black?

Comment: @Jerod4444 what do you mean with "black text is not preserved"? Is the text disappearing, or getting a different color?

Answer (score 0):

To access the text color of single characters within a cell, you can use the `Characters`-property of the cell. To get, for example, the font color of the 10th character within a cell, you write `cell.Characters(10, 1).Font.Color`. The 2nd parameter is the number of characters you want to fetch. If those characters have *different* formatting, you will get `null` as result.

So now the first part is to split the text into lines (as you do in your code). Then we need to loop over the single lines and check if they are formatted in red. If yes, we append the word `*term`.

After that we can apply the words back into the cell using the join-operator. However, the formatting within the cell gets lost, so we need to reapply the red color to the words we just marked. We therefore loop another time over all the words and set to color for marked words back to red.

The following routine will do this for one cell

```
Sub markColoredText(cell As Range, color As Long, suffix As String)
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit Sub
    Dim lines() As String, lineNo As Long
    lines = Split(cell.Value, vbLf)
    ReDim needsColor(0 To UBound(lines)) As Boolean
    
    Dim startWordPos As Long, wordlen As Long
    startWordPos = 1
    For lineNo = 0 To UBound(lines)
        wordlen = Len(lines(lineNo))
        If cell.Characters(startWordPos, wordlen).Font.color = color Then
            If Right(lines(lineNo), Len(suffix)) <> suffix Then
                lines(lineNo) = lines(lineNo) & suffix
            End If
            needsColor(lineNo) = True   ' Remember that we need to format this
        End If
        startWordPos = startWordPos + wordlen + 1
    Next
    
    ' Write back the text --> This will remove the color
    cell.Value = Join(lines, vbLf)
    
    ' reapply the color for marked lines
    startWordPos = 1
    For lineNo = 0 To UBound(lines)
        wordlen = Len(lines(lineNo))
        If needsColor(lineNo) Then
            cell.Characters(startWordPos, wordlen).Font.color = color
        End If
        startWordPos = startWordPos + wordlen + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Now write a small routine that loops over your relevant data and call this routine:

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, cell As Range
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set r = Intersect(ws.Range("D:M"), ws.usedRange)
 For each cell in r
    markColoredText cell, vbRed, "*term"
 Next
```

Be warned: I have tested this only with single cells, I could image that it takes some time to process a large sheet.

Comment: Thank you.  I put the subroutine in a module as a Sub loopThrough() so that I could execute it, and it gave an error on the 4th line of code for markColoredText, "Subscript out of range".  How did you execute the subroutine?

Comment: @Jerod4444: I guess this happens when you pass an empty cell. I added a check at the top of the routine, this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Another one.  *Almost* works right...

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In [B1:B10]
        c.Offset(0, 1).Copy c 'refresh for for testing purposes
        checkTerm c
    Next c
End Sub

Sub checkTerm(c As Range)
    Const CLR As Long = vbRed
    Const SUFFIX As String = "*term"
    Dim pos As Long, v As String, done As Boolean, n As Long
    
    v = c.Value
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do
        n = n + 1
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, v, vbLf)
        done = (pos = 0) 'no more lines
        If done Then pos = Len(v) + 1
        Debug.Print c.Address, pos, done
        If c.Characters(pos - 1, 1).Font.Color = CLR Then
            c.Characters(pos, 0).Insert SUFFIX
            c.Characters(pos, Len(SUFFIX)).Font.Color = CLR
            pos = pos + (Len(SUFFIX) - 1) 'account for inserted text
            v = c.Value
        End If
        pos = pos + 1
        If done Then Exit Do
        If n > 5 Then Exit Do
    Loop While pos > 0
End Sub
```